# how can I set the resolution for raspbmc via xml

Tags: raspbmc

I would like to set the resolution via the xml configuration files.  Is this possible? I can ssh into the pi and see .xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml.  Opening this file show resolution options, but I don't know how to chose one.  I have also looked in .profiles.xml with no luck.  I need to be able to set via xml.

Thanks for any help you can provide!  I am a new pi user so sorry if this is a basic question, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Are you talking about screen resolution? Are you using HDMI or composite (analog) video output?

Comment: Yes, screen resolution.  I am using an HDMI cable.